# Changes in GCE/kubernetes - no display of the finished pods

Tags: google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform, kubernetes

All

running computation Monte Carlo jobs on Google Compute Engine. Last time I ran them was September, and things have changed a bit since then. I used to run a lot of jobs with `kubectl` from some pod.json file, no RC, no restart, fire-and-forget setup. After I started jobs I used to get pods (`kubectl get pods`) and typically output looks like

```
NAME                READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
r8o3il08c25-y0z10   1/1       Running   0          56m
r8o3il08c25-y0z15   0/1       Pending   0          56m
```

After one is done and second is started, I used to get output

```
NAME                READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
r8o3il08c25-y0z10   1/1       Exit:0    0          1h
r8o3il08c25-y0z15   1/1       Running   0          1h
```

So I could, using simple `grep`, get the picture how many are running, how many are pending, and how many are done, and query exit code (so to check if there are errors with some pods) etc

Now output with latest SDK (Google Cloud SDK 0.9.87) looks like this

```
NAME      READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
```

All finished pods are now invisible.

Could I get old behavior back? Why it was changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[PR #12112](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/12112) changed `kubectl get pods` to not show terminated pods by default. You can get the old behavior (show all pods) by using `kubectl get pods -a`

Comment: Thank you. I thought about option, but tried `--all` which is used for `kubectl get pods`, and it didn't work. Any reason for such inconsistency in options?

Comment: kubectl uses `--all` to mean something else in other places, and it was decided that using it here might be confusing (see https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/12112#issuecomment-127420398). Sounds like it ended up being confusing the other way :)